# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Python

Tags: python, java, excel

I can't understand that this error is regarding to Java or Python. I tried to configure Java to increase the size, but it failed. This code is written in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import  jpype
import numpy
import pandas
import win32com.client as win32
import os
import pyspark
import EasyExcel 
from xlrd import open_workbook
import  asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook
workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile.xlsx")
workbook.save(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile1.xlsb")
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Error

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_jpype.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in com.aspose.cells.Workbook.save()

Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6056\723174829.py in <module>
      6 from asposecells.api import Workbook
      7 workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile.xlsx")
----> 8 workbook.save(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile1.xlsb")
      9 jpype.shutdownJVM()

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I want the output is to save the xlsb file in small data format.

Comment: _"I tried to configure Java to increase the size, but it failed."_ How did you try, because your question shows no attempt to configure the memory for Java.

Comment: Hii  
Mark Rotteveel, I increase this configure Java but i worked on python thats why this shown this error the heap space got error to load the file and save the xlsb file not supported..

Answer (score 0):

From https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#controlling-the-jvm you can send arguments to `startJVM`.

If you want to increase max memory you would use `jpype.startJVM("-Xmx2g")`. Adjust the actual size to what is needed.

Run `java --help` or `java -X` to get available options.

Comment: Not worked given answer @Roger Lindsjö

Comment: What did you change the setting to? Does it work if you run just the Java process outside Python?

Comment: I done with jpype.startJVM("-Xmx2g") but not helped first time its work properly with 100Mb file but when i used 400Mb file same error are occure

Comment: Have you tried to adjust it up to say 4g or 8g?

Comment: Yes now it is working i just use jpype.startJVM("-Xmx10g") then it takes time and load. If any problem i will tell you again for now thank you so much @Roger Lindsjö

Comment: Hii @Roger Lindsjö, their is new problem i faced this is i give a path but in live how can i run this code with out given path ?                                                                 import  jpype
import  asposecells
jpype.startJVM("-Xmx10g")
from asposecells.api import Workbook
workbook = Workbook(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(r"TestFile.xlsx")))
workbook.save(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\TestFile2.xlsb")
jpype.shutdownJVM()

Comment: `import  jpype
import  asposecells
import urllib.request
jpype.startJVM("-Xmx10g")
from asposecells.api import Workbook
workbook = Workbook("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile.xlsx")
workbook.save("http://localhost/cafe_ci/assets/TestFile2.xlsb")
jpype.shutdownJVM()`

Comment: You can not save to a http URL. But ask a separate question, what you mean by live, where the file is and where you want it saved.

Comment: if i run this code in live server okay then i cannot pass this **C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\** url so i just need the a url https like this but now i tried to used in my php file localhost to check the file is downloaded using the url or not.